How to combine multiple citations into a single set of parentheses using BibLaTeX?
I am using BibLaTeX with the authoryear style for my citations. Currently, when I cite multiple references, they appear as separate sets of parentheses. For example:
\parencite{zhang2017mdnet, zhang2017tandemnet}

produces:
(Zhang, Xie vd. 2017); (Zhang, P. Chen vd. 2017)

However, I would like them to appear within a single set of parentheses, separated by a semicolon, like this:
(Zhang, Xie vd. 2017; Zhang, P. Chen vd. 2017)

but in single entries it should stay as:
input: \parencite{zhang2017mdnet)
output: (Zhang, Xie vd. 2017)

Here is the BibLaTeX setup I am currently using:
% Load the BibLaTeX package with the specified options
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=999, giveninits=true]{biblatex}

% Remove the "In:" prefix from citations
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\textnormal{#1}}

% Load the xpatch package to modify BibLaTeX macros
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Add the bibliography file
\addbibresource{my_references.bib}

% Remove the parentheses from around the date in the default citation style
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

% Add parentheses only around the year in citations
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Redefine the \cite command to place parentheses around the year only
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}} % Pre-note
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}% Citation index
   \printnames{labelname}% Print author names
   \setunit{\nameyeardelim}% Separator between name and year
   \printfield{labelyear}} % Print year with parentheses
  {\addsemicolon\space} % Separator for multiple citations
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}} % Post-note

% Redefine the \parencite command to place parentheses around the entire citation
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}} % Pre-note
  {\printtext[parens]{%
     \usebibmacro{citeindex}% Citation index
     \printnames{labelname}% Print author names
     \setunit{\nameyeardelim}% Separator between name and year
     \printfield{year}}} % Print year without parentheses
  {\addsemicolon\space} % Separator for multiple citations
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}} % Post-note

% Set the multicitedelim to a semicolon followed by a space
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% Format the title field with quotes and a comma
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{``#1''\addcomma}

% Format the journaltitle field with a comma
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1\addcomma}

% Define custom strings for Turkish
\DefineBibliographyStrings{turkish}{%
  andothers = {vd\adddot} % 'and others' in Turkish
}

% Format the pages field without any additional text
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% Set name alias to display family name first
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

% Custom format for bibliography entries without parentheses around the year
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}

% Custom format for books
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}% Print author/editor
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printfield{year}\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}% Print title
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}\addcomma \newunit\newblock% Print edition
  \printfield{location}\addcolon \newunit\newblock% Print location
  \printfield{publisher}\adddot \newunit\newblock% Print publisher
  \finentry}

% Custom format for incollection (book chapters)
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{author}% Print author
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printfield{year}\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}% Print title
  \newunit\newblock
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\space}% Print 'in'
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}% Print editor
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{booktitle}% Print book title
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pages}\addcomma \newunit\newblock% Print pages
  \printfield{location}\addcolon \newunit\newblock% Print location
  \printfield{publisher}\adddot \newunit\newblock% Print publisher
  \finentry}

% Custom format for inproceedings (conference papers)
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{author}% Print author
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printfield{year}\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}% Print title
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{booktitle}\addcomma% Print book title (proceedings)
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{location}\addcolon% Print location
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{publisher}\adddot% Print publisher
  \newunit\newblock
  \finentry}

% Custom format for articles
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{author}% Print author
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printfield{year}\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}% Print title
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{journaltitle}\addcomma% Print journal title 
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volume}\addcomma% Print volume
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pages}\adddot% Print pages
  \newunit\newblock
  \finentry}


\parencite behaves like you want by default, but the code shown in the question uses some unidiomatic expressions that mess with this behaviour.
If you get rid of the code block
% Remove the parentheses from around the date in the default citation style
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

% Add parentheses only around the year in citations
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Redefine the \cite command to place parentheses around the year only
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}} % Pre-note
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}% Citation index
   \printnames{labelname}% Print author names
   \setunit{\nameyeardelim}% Separator between name and year
   \printfield{labelyear}} % Print year with parentheses
  {\addsemicolon\space} % Separator for multiple citations
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}} % Post-note

% Redefine the \parencite command to place parentheses around the entire citation
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}} % Pre-note
  {\printtext[parens]{%
     \usebibmacro{citeindex}% Citation index
     \printnames{labelname}% Print author names
     \setunit{\nameyeardelim}% Separator between name and year
     \printfield{year}}} % Print year without parentheses
  {\addsemicolon\space} % Separator for multiple citations
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}} % Post-note

you should get the desired behaviour back.
